# Confusion on Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Urn 1: $1$ blue ball, $3$ red balls

Urn 2: $3$ blue balls, $1$ red ball

Suppose you take a ball at random without knowing which urn you took it from. Both urns are equally likely. Using Bayes’ rule, compute the probability of a majority-blue bin after two blue balls in a row. What is this probability?

It was computed in a previous problem that the probability of drawing two blue balls in a row is $\frac{5}{16}$ The probablity of drawing from urn 2 would be $\frac{1}{2}$ and the probability of picking a blue ball from that urn is $\frac{3}{4}$.

$\frac{\frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{5}{16}}$
$=\frac{6}{5}$

I'm confused on where the flaw is in my computation/thinking, thank you!

Comment: "and the probability of picking a blue ball..." why just one? You have to pick *two* blue balls. So, the numerator becomes $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{4})^2$.

Comment: Are you taking both balls from the same unknown urn, or from possibly different urns? In the latter case, which urn are we calculating the probability for?

Comment: Quote: **"** ... compute the probability of a majority-blue bin after two blue balls in a row **"** I have to admit that I´m not sure what is asked for. Could you rephrase/explain it ?

Comment: @calculus: Presumably we select an urn, the select twice, with replacement, from that urn.  But, yes, if this is so it needs to be clearly stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably we select an urn, the select twice, with replacement, from that urn.

(Because if we are selecting a different urn each time the question makes little sense, and if we are selecting without replacement from the same urn then we would certainly be selecting two blue balls from the urn with more than one ball.)

The probability of selecting two blue balls, with replacement between selections, from urn 1 is $\mathsf P(B{=}2\mid U{=}1)={(\tfrac {1}{4})}^2$

The probability of selecting two blue balls, with replacement between selections, from urn 1 is $\mathsf P(B{=}2\mid U{=}2)={(\tfrac {3}{4})}^2$

As noted, the probability of selecting each urn is equal, so what you wanted was:

$$\mathsf P(U{=}2\mid B{=}2) = \dfrac{(\tfrac 12){(\tfrac {3}{4})}^2}{(\tfrac 12){(\tfrac {3}{4})}^2+(\tfrac 12){(\tfrac {1}{4})}^2}=0.9$$

Where as you had:

$$\dfrac{(\tfrac 12){(\tfrac {3}{4})}}{\tfrac {5}{16}}$$

> I'm confused on where the flaw is in my computation/thinking

You clearly have the right denominator, as $(\tfrac 12){(\tfrac {3}{4})}^2+(\tfrac 12){(\tfrac {1}{4})}^2=\tfrac 5{16}$, so it looks like you made a simple typo, and dropped the square from the numerator.   Better look on the floor.